# Reactive Cocoa reduce block never gets called

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to wrap head around Reactive Cocoa, everything works fine except `RAC(self.windButton.enabled)` sections (at the bottom), reduce blocks never gets called. Would be glad if someone could point me my errors. The code is self-explaining, basically app looks like this:

[image: App screenshot]

Here is implementation

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *winding;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *minWinding;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *maxWinding;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *windButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *unwindButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *windingLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.winding = @0;
    self.minWinding = @0;
    self.maxWinding = @15;

    RACSignal *windingSignal = RACAble(self.winding);
    RACSignal *maxWindingSignal = RACAble(self.maxWinding);
    RACSignal *minWindingSignal = RACAble(self.minWinding);

    RAC(self.windingLabel.text) = [windingSignal map:^id(NSNumber *winding) {
        return winding.stringValue;
    }];

    [[self.windButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
     subscribeNext:^(id sender) {
        self.winding = @(self.winding.integerValue + 1);
    }];

    [[self.unwindButton rac_signalForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
     subscribeNext:^(id sender) {
        self.winding = @(self.winding.integerValue - 1);
    }];

    RAC(self.windButton.enabled) = [RACSignal
                              combineLatest:@[windingSignal, maxWindingSignal]
                              reduce:^(NSNumber *winding, NSNumber *maxWinding) {
                                  return @(winding.intValue < maxWinding.intValue);
                              }];


    RAC(self.unwindButton.enabled) = [RACSignal
                               combineLatest:@[windingSignal, minWindingSignal]
                               reduce:^(NSNumber *winding, NSNumber *minWinding) {
                                   return @(winding.intValue > minWinding.intValue);
                               }];
}
```

My problem is that buttons never get disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `RACAbleWithStart` to pre-fill signal with initial values since `combineLatest` method waits until every provided signal has some value.

```
RACSignal *windingSignal = RACAbleWithStart(self.winding);
RACSignal *maxWindingSignal = RACAbleWithStart(self.maxWinding);
RACSignal *minWindingSignal = RACAbleWithStart(self.minWinding);
```

Answer (score 0):

The RAC() macro takes two arguments at a minimum.

check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266886/enabling-an-uibutton-using-reactive-cocoa-racsignal)

Comment: Back in the days one arg was enough :-)

Comment: Have you solved you problem? How can I help you? Should I write a demo code with ReactiveCocoa latest version for you?