# Enabling an UIButton using Reactive Cocoa RACSignal

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I have a `UIButton` added to a view. My view also has three text box viz. **username**, **password** and **confirmPassword**. Based on the legitimate content of these text box, I need to enable my **signUp** button.

Here is my code snippet :-

```
    UIButton *signUp = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 50, 20)];
    signUp.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    signUp.enabled = NO ;
    [self.view addSubview:signUp];

    RACSignal *formValid = [RACSignal
    combineLatest:@[
    username.rac_textSignal,
    password.rac_textSignal,
    confirmPassword.rac_textSignal
    ]
    reduce:^(NSString *username, NSString *password, NSString *passwordVerification)        {
    return @([username length] > 0 && [password length] > 8 && [password      isEqual:passwordVerification]);
    }];

    RAC(signUp.enabled) = formValid; //Error is here
```

In the last line, I'm getting two errors:-

1. Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
2. Expected identifier

I am new to Reactive Cocoa. Please ignore the mistakes.

Comment: it seems that the code shown is correct. I think that your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Your code *was* correct in older versions of ReactiveCocoa, for current versions see the answers below.

Comment: you must typcast rac line this can defrag stack element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `RAC()` macro takes two arguments at a minimum, the object that's the target and a valid keypath on that object.

Like so:

```
RAC(signUp, enabled) = formValid;
```

You're passing it `signUp.enabled`, which is a single item, and happens to be a `BOOL`, not an object. After the macro is expanded, the `BOOL` is passed to a method that expects an object argument, so the compiler complains:

```
[[RACSubscriptingAssignmentTrampoline alloc] initWithTarget:signUp.enabled nilValue:<#garbage#>][@keypath(signUp.enabled, nil)]
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `RAC(signUp, enabled)` instead of `RAC(signUp.enabled)`. The `RAC` macro takes at least two arguments, the object and the keypath you are binding.